# How can I shorten this function jQuery?

Tags: jquery, image, function, gallery

How can I shorten this so that it all fits in one function. I have a working image gallery, when image with class a is clicked the image in class bigimg is changed to the one selected. I've probably done a long way of changing the images but there will only be a dozen max.

Btw I will host my images these are just for my test

**HTML/ jQuery**

```
<div id="galleryholder">

            <div id="largeimg" class="center">
                <img class="bigimg" src="http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-BNkayp7vphQ/UEmx3WTwe1I/AAAAAAAAELg/eHu4hWtoXbk/s1600/desktop-wallpaper-29.jpg">
            </div>

            <div id="reel">
                <a href=""><img class="a" src="http://wallpaperstate.org/wp-content/gallery/ca_home/hd-wallpaper-30.jpg"></a>
                <a href="#"><img class="b" src="http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-BNkayp7vphQ/UEmx3WTwe1I/AAAAAAAAELg/eHu4hWtoXbk/s1600/desktop-wallpaper-29.jpg"></a>
                <a href="#"><img class="c" src="http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-BNkayp7vphQ/UEmx3WTwe1I/AAAAAAAAELg/eHu4hWtoXbk/s1600/desktop-wallpaper-29.jpg"></a>
            </div>

                <script>
                $(function() {

                  $('.a').click(function(){
                    $(".bigimg").attr('src',"http://wallpaperstate.org/wp-content/gallery/ca_home/hd-wallpaper-30.jpg");
                    return false;
                  });
                });


                $(function() {
                  $('.b').click(function(){
                    $(".bigimg").attr('src',"http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-BNkayp7vphQ/UEmx3WTwe1I/AAAAAAAAELg/eHu4hWtoXbk/s1600/desktop-wallpaper-29.jpg");
                    return false;
                  });
                });
                </script>

        </div>
```

Answer (score 8):

Pull the `src` dynamically from the clicked image:

```
var $big = $(".bigimg");

$('#reel img').click(function () {
    $big.attr('src', this.src);
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Works, thanks, however the page reloads, do I need the return false agaim?

Comment: Near in mind that `this.src` isn't always the same as `$('this').attr('src')`.

Comment: @DavidThomas - True, but I don't see how that would affect what the OP is trying to do.

Comment: Oh it probably wouldn't, really was just intended as a head's-up is all.

Comment: @JonathanLockley, you should really start accepting answers. It's way faster and more appreciated than commenting: "Thanks, it works".
Maybe you give the FAQ (http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask) a shot ;-)

Answer (score 0):

```
        <div id="largeimg" class="center">
            <img class="bigimg" src="http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-BNkayp7vphQ/UEmx3WTwe1I/AAAAAAAAELg/eHu4hWtoXbk/s1600/desktop-wallpaper-29.jpg">
        </div>

        <div id="reel">
            <a href=""><img class="a" src="http://wallpaperstate.org/wp-content/gallery/ca_home/hd-wallpaper-30.jpg"></a>
            <a href="#"><img class="a" src="http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-BNkayp7vphQ/UEmx3WTwe1I/AAAAAAAAELg/eHu4hWtoXbk/s1600/desktop-wallpaper-29.jpg"></a>
            <a href="#"><img class="a" src="http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-BNkayp7vphQ/UEmx3WTwe1I/AAAAAAAAELg/eHu4hWtoXbk/s1600/desktop-wallpaper-29.jpg"></a>
        </div>

            <script>
            $(function() {
              $('.a').click(function(e){
                $(".bigimg").attr('src',$(this).attr('src'));
                e.preventDefault();
              });
            });
            </script>
```